# Print array from lowest to greatest

Tags: c++, arrays, bubble-sort

I am working on a project to print an array of numbers from least to greatest. Right now I am only printing the largest number. I have been researching for 2 days and can not find the answer. Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int max(double nSalaries[])
{
    double highest = nSalaries[0];

    int index = 0;

    for(int j = 1; j < 10; j++)
    {

        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(nSalaries[i] > highest)
            {
                highest = nSalaries[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "What's the highest?: " << highest << endl;

    nSalaries [index] = 0;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{

    double nSalaries[] = {256, 734, 201, 3, 123, 40, 99, 257, 7, 609};

    cout << max(nSalaries );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cut and dried: Nowhere in the code do you attempt to print more than one number.

Comment: You have tagged this `[bubble-sort]` - we expect you to try implementing it yourself rather than write the code for you. (And Insertion Sort is most often better and simpler, and since this is `[c++]` you should be using `std::vector`)

Comment: Oh, and `using namespace std;` and declaring a function called `max()` may cause unexpected problems later if you `#include <algorithm>`.

Comment: I see no sorting whatsoever in the code you posted.  All you have is a function to get the maximum value.  *I have been researching for 2 days and can not find the answer.* -- Seriously, implementing a bubble sort is explained all over the web.